# Possible to derive attributes *after* a struct declaration?

Tags: macros, rust

I'm using a macro to extend a primitive struct:

```
pub struct MyTypedNumber(pub u32);
struct_impl_my_features!(MyTypedNumber);
```

The `struct_impl_my_features` macro can implement functions & traits for `MyTypedNumber`, however there is a case where its useful to use `#[derive(PartialEq, Eq)]` - for example.

Is it possible to use `#[derive(...)]` after the struct is already declared?

An alternative is to pass in the struct definition as an `item` argument to a macro:

```
struct_impl_my_features!(
    pub struct MyTypedNumber(pub u32);,
    MyTypedNumber
);
```

This works, so it may be the best option, although it is rather clunky and means the declaration and macro extension must be together.

See [this complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40336386/432509), the macro is called `struct_bitflag_impl` (second example).

---

I worked around this by manually implementing `PartialEq` and `Eq`, however I ran into a case where Rust *needs* `#[derive(...)]` to be used as constants within `match` statement:

```
= warning: this was previously accepted by the compiler but is being phased out;
  it will become a hard error in a future release!
= note: for more information,
  see RFC 1445 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1445>
```

Comment: Can you please include a complete example?  What has MyTypedNumber got to do with MyTypedInt?

Comment: `MyTypedInt` accidentally left in, corrected - added link to complete example.

Comment: Derive doesn't do anything magical. You should be able to do the exact same implementation manually that it does. Could you provide the example where you feel you need derive?

Comment: @paholg, thats what I would have expected too and its true in most cases, however the Rust compiler is deprecating support for non-derive equality, see: RFC 1445.

Answer (score 0):

The "complete example" link you provide **does** show an example of having the macro prefix attributes (see the second macro).

```
    #[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Copy, Clone, Debug)]
    $struct_p_def
```

However, if instead you want to be able to provide derive-attributes per struct (e.g., only some of your structs need to derive `PartialEq`), you can pass the derive expression in the first part of your second `struct_impl_my_features!` example—the attributes are considered part of the `item` macro form. E.g.,

```
struct_impl_my_features!(
    #[derive(PartialEq, Eq)]
    pub struct MyTypedNumber(pub u32);,
    MyTypedNumber
);
```

**Update**

Sorry, I don't have an answer to your main question; as far as I know, it is not possible. However, if your primary concern is the clunkiness, and if your structs are all of similar form, you could make your macro call nicer by adding this to the top of your macro:

```
($x:ident ( $($v:tt)* ) ) => {
    struct_impl_my_features!(pub struct $x( $($v)* );, $x)
};
```

And then calling it like:

```
struct_impl_my_features!(MyTypedNumber(pub u32));
```

Comment: I updated the second macro example linked from this question after asking. Even so, the ability to use derive after defining a struct would be useful since its a little cumbersome to pass a struct definition into a macro. Updated the question.