# Is it possible to nest a struct declaration in a macro to apply struct attributes?

Tags: macros, rust

If we want to generalize applying `#[derive(...)]` to a struct, in some cases it would  be useful to wrap this in a macro.

non-working example:

```
my_traits!(
    pub struct MyType(u32),
    MyType
);
```

Where `my_traits` could prefix the first argument with `#[derive(...)]`, and use the second argument to declare `impl SomeTrait for $t {...}`.

Declaring implementations works without any problems, however I didn't manage to find a way to use a macro to prefix the struct declaration with attributes.

---

See this question for an example of what this could be used for:
[Possible to derive attributes *after* a struct declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40401574)

Answer (score 3):

Putting `#[derive(...)]` into the macro seems to work fine:

```
#[derive(Eq,PartialEq,Debug)]
struct Foo(u32);

macro_rules! my_eq(
    ($name:ident) => {
        #[derive(Eq,PartialEq,Debug)]
        struct $name(u32);
    };
);

my_eq!(Bar);

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(Foo(3), Foo(3));
    assert!(Foo(3) != Foo(4));
    assert_eq!(Bar(3), Bar(3));
    assert!(Bar(3) != Bar(4));

}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8d1c8aae985a7c46a17c33779f3f4526&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Or if you want to pass the whole `struct` in:

```
macro_rules! my_eq(
    ($name:item) => {
        #[derive(Eq,PartialEq,Debug)]
        $name
    };
);

my_eq!(struct Bar(u32););
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c92ef69c9b95f7a23710807ff994cc8f&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Note that the macro takes an entire item, so the semicolon inside the macro call is needed (`Foo{}` structs don't need it, just like when written inline).

Comment: Thanks, I might end up doing this. The main down-side to this - while this works, I wanted to pass in the entire declaration, otherwise Ill need to make separate macros for `pub struct $name(u32);` and `struct $name(pub u32);` (public struct and public member).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by passing in an `item`, answer thanks to @j_ey on IRC.

```
macro_rules! ideas {
    ($ty: item, $id: ident) => {
        #[derive(Debug)]
        $ty
        impl $id {
            fn doit(){}
        }
    }
}

ideas!(pub struct Foo(u32);, Foo);

fn main() {
    let f = Foo(1);
    println!("{:?}", f);
}
```