# Is it possible to access the type of a struct member for function signatures or declarations?

Tags: rust

When defining implementations in macros, it might be useful to access a struct members type to avoid having to pass it as an extra argument. (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40336386/432509))

```
impl PartialEq<u32> for MyStruct { ... }
```

Is there a way to access the type of a struct member without knowing in advance which type it is?

```
impl PartialEq<typeof(MyStruct.member)> for MyStruct { ... }
```

---

In case it's helpful, this is an abbreviated example of why I'm interested to do this:

```
struct_bitflag_impl!(
    pub struct MyFlag(u8);,
    MyFlag, u8);

//          ^^ how to avoid having this extra arg?
//             (Used by ``impl PartialEq<$t_internal> for $p``)
//             couldn't it be discovered from `MyFlag.0` ?

// the macro

macro_rules! struct_bitflag_impl {
    ($struct_p_def: item, $p:ident, $t_internal:ty) => {

        #[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Copy, Clone, Debug)]
        $struct_p_def

        impl ::std::ops::BitAnd for $p {
            type Output = $p;
            fn bitand(self, _rhs: $p) -> $p { $p(self.0 & _rhs.0) }
        }
        impl ::std::ops::BitOr for $p {
            type Output = $p;
            fn bitor(self, _rhs: $p) -> $p { $p(self.0 | _rhs.0) }
        }
        impl ::std::ops::BitXor for $p {
            type Output = $p;
            fn bitxor(self, _rhs: $p) -> $p { $p(self.0 ^ _rhs.0) }
        }

        impl ::std::ops::Not for $p {
            type Output = $p;
            fn not(self) -> $p { $p(!self.0) }
        }

        // support comparison with the base-type.
        impl PartialEq<$t_internal> for $p {
            fn eq(&self, other: &t_internal) -> bool {
                self.0 == *other
            }
        }
        // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        //       How to avoid using 't_internal' here?
    }
}
```

Comment: Comment from @keepr, this could be handled by `custom_derive` see: https://docs.rs/custom_derive/*/custom_derive/index.html

Answer (score 5):

No, a general `typeof(Type::field)` that can be used in type position does not exist.

---

Regarding the example in the question, it looks like you are expecting a special kind of item: a tuple-struct with only one field. So, instead of accepting an `$item` fragment, you can simulate the syntax yourself:

```
macro_rules! foo {
    (pub struct $name:ident ( $ty:ident ) ) => {
        pub struct $name($ty);

        impl $name {
            pub fn bar() { 
                println!("{}", stringify!($ty)); 
            }
        }
    }
}

foo!(
    pub struct Peter(u8)
);

fn main() {
    Peter::bar();
}
```

That way you only have to specify everything once. However, this obviously only works with one kind of tuple-struct definition, not all kinds of items. But your use case suggests that you are more or less only interested in this special case.

If you want to allow different kinds of struct definitions, you just need to add more macro-rules to the macro to allow for different syntax. To see an example, [here is code to allow for `pub` and non-`pub` tuple-struct definitions](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=34f0c0d3b29503d32c342ffdc95b3f9f&version=stable&backtrace=0). But this could be expanded even more.

Comment: Doesn't this hard code public/private for both the struct and its internal member? eg, you might want to do `struct Peter(pub u8)` or `pub struct Peter(u8)`

Comment: @ideasman42 Absolutely, this is very hardcoded for a specific case. If you want the flexibility of `pub` and non-`pub` you can add more macro "arms"...  let me try to build a nicer version and link it in the question. Please stand by ;-)

Comment: Great, updated my code to use this style of macro https://gitlab.com/ideasman42/bmesh-rs/blob/master/bmesh/src/bitflag_macros.rs  - still not sure how `Peter(u8)` and `Peter(pub u8)` would be done though.

Comment: Update, both struct visibility and inner variable visibility can be pattern matched, edited; https://gitlab.com/ideasman42/bmesh-rs/blob/master/bmesh/src/bitflag_macros.rs