# Does Rust have an equivalent to C++'s decltype() to get the type of an expression?

Tags: rust

My code looks like:

```rust
macro_rules! mask {
    ($bitmap: tt, [..$count: tt], for type = $ty: ty) => {
        {
            let bit_count = std::mem::size_of::<$ty>() * 8;
            let dec_bit_count = bit_count - 1;
            $bitmap & [(1 << ($count & dec_bit_count)) - 1, <$ty>::MAX][((($count & !dec_bit_count)) != 0) as usize]
        }
    };
}

fn main() {
    let bitmap: u8 = 0b_1111_1111;
    let masked_bitmap = mask!(bitmap, [..5], for type = u8);
    println!("{:#010b}", masked_bitmap);
}
```

The above code will mask the bitmap. In the above example, `0b_1111_1111` on being masked by `[..5]` will become `0b_0001_1111`.

I want my macro to be like this:

```rust
macro_rules! mask {
    ($bitmap: tt, [..$count: tt]) => {
        {
            let bit_count = std::mem::size_of::<decltype($bitmap)>() * 8;
            let dec_bit_count = bit_count - 1;
            $bitmap & [(1 << ($count & dec_bit_count)) - 1, <decltype($bitmap)>::MAX][((($count & !dec_bit_count)) != 0) as usize]
        }
    };
}
```

But I have to pass type to the macro to get this done. Is there something like `decltype()` from C++ that I could use?

Comment: You can remove all instances of the type if you use `mem::size_of_val ($bitmap)` instead of `mem::size_of::<$ty>()` and `~0` instead of `<$ty>::MAX` (since your macro only makes sense for unsigned integer types anyway).

Comment: @Jmb, will `mem::size_of_val()` be interpreted at compile time by any optimisation? I tried what you are saying before. `mem::size_of()` is const func so it gets resolved at compile time but I wasn't sure about `size_of_val`.

Comment: According to [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.size_of_val.html), `size_of_val` is the same as `size_of::<T>()` unless the size of `T` cannot be known at compile-time, in which case it is evaluated at run-time whereas `size_of::<T>()` fails to compile.

Comment: And godbolt shows that [it is optimized at compile time](https://godbolt.org/z/YfYMEP).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, Rust does not have the ability to get the type of an arbitrary expression. `typeof` *is* a reserved keyword to potentially allow it in the future:

```
fn main() {
    let a: i32 = 42;
    let b: typeof(a) = a;
}
```

```
error[E0516]: `typeof` is a reserved keyword but unimplemented
 --> src/main.rs:3:12
  |
3 |     let b: typeof(a) = a;
  |            ^^^^^^^^^ reserved keyword
```

There are RFCs suggesting that it be added.

See also:

- [How do I match the type of an expression in a Rust macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34214136/155423)
- [Is it possible to access the type of a struct member for function signatures or declarations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40573055/155423)
- [.type` for getting concrete type of a binding — issue #2704](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/2704)

---

For your specific case, I would use traits instead:

```rust
use std::ops::RangeTo;

trait Mask {
    fn mask(self, range: RangeTo<usize>) -> Self;
}

impl Mask for u8 {
    #[inline]
    fn mask(self, range: RangeTo<usize>) -> Self {
        // Feel free to make this your more complicated bitwise logic
        let mut m = 0;
        for _ in 0..range.end {
            m <<= 1;
            m |= 1;
        }
        self & m
    }
}


fn main() {
    let bitmap: u8 = 0b_1111_1111;
    let masked_bitmap = bitmap.mask(..5);
    println!("{:#010b}", masked_bitmap);
}
```

You could use macros to *implement the trait* however:

```rust
macro_rules! impl_mask {
    ($($typ:ty),*) => {
        $(
            impl Mask for $typ {
                #[inline]
                fn mask(self, range: RangeTo<usize>) -> Self {
                    let mut m = 0;
                    for _ in 0..range.end {
                        m <<= 1;
                        m |= 1;
                    }
                    self & m
                }
            }
        )*
    };
}

impl_mask!(u8, u16, u32, u64, u128);
```